# PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am developing an application in cordova but my barcode scanner from Zxing opens and closes Automatically after scanning the product in need to add a scan/exit button and a close button the scanner shouldnt open and close automatically. I also need to check if  the scanned product exist in the database (SQL SERVER) and return product infomation i have tried to google but to no avail please help.the following is my code in Eclipse. I need to know how i can modify The UI and add my own control of my ZXING barcode scanner plugin i am developing in  Eclipse and have a web api service hosted in IIS which i can access on my android App.Please ASAP or show me how i can modify this barcode UI to ADD my controls.

```
public void scan() {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(SCAN_INTENT);
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

My OnStartActivity code is here  is the code but it seems like it is the same as yours.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put(TEXT, intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
                obj.put(FORMAT, intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
                obj.put(CANCELLED, false);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This should never happen");
            }
            //this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj), this.callback);
            this.callbackContext.success(obj);
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put(TEXT, "");
                obj.put(FORMAT, "");
                obj.put(CANCELLED, true);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This should never happen");
            }
            //this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj), this.callback);
            this.callbackContext.success(obj);
        } else {
            //this.error(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR), this.callback);
            this.callbackContext.error("Unexpected error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon I have an app that do what you are looking for... first of all I create an intent so i can use any QR scanner I use an external app in order to get the value of the QR code here.

```
 public void scanNow(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

so in my onStartActivity for result send that info to the server side and I wait for the answer...

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");// here is the content of the qr scanner
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            String messLoc = "Visita Guardada Con Exito";
            Log.i("xZing", "contents: " + contents + " format: " + format);// Handle successful scan
            Toast.makeText(this, messLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new Thread(new Task()).start(); // here I start the thread for the connection 
            return;
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED);{// Handle cancel
        Log.i("xZing", "Cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this help you

Comment: i have edited and posted my code that was already there but it is still not working

Comment: Sorry for late reply... so it still doing the same thing.. it opens the scanner and close inmediatly... try to use another QR scanner... I recomend you to use QR Droid

Comment: Ayt thank you does the QR Droid work better than than the ZXIng ?

Comment: Problem is i am using a Phonegap Application does QR code also work Phonegap/cordova

Comment: It actually does... it's faster and its more friendly than ZXing... I mean if you are ussing an external app to read the QR content QR Droid it's pretty good... let me know if that solved your problem...

Comment: Ayt thank you i will let u know how i go around it thanks for your help much appreciated

Comment: Can you Please provide a step by step instructions or share a link where i can use the QR Droid with my Android Application

Comment: Let me look it up... gust give me some minutes

Comment: I was looking for a tutorial but none was very explicit on it... did you install QR droid... let me tell you for example when you click a button that is going to trigger the QR scanner what happen... it happens the same thing with all the scanners???

Comment: Yes i downloaded and installed the QR Droid when i click it kinda freezes but scans but how will i actually incorporate this with my Android(phonegap) app or is there an alternative  for this

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
I just started using Zbar instead Zxing. It's a whole lot easier to work with. Extremely easy to embed (no 3rd party app for the scanner). It has a lot let file to load into the project. Also, it has an included example that you can pretty much copy and paste into your code. The example is perfect for what you are trying to do and would only require a few edits to gain the functions you are looking for.  So try using the zbar library. 
Zbar - https://github.com/dm77/ZBarScanner 
A tutorial - http://community.magicsoftware.com/en/library?book=en/Magicxpa/&page=Android_Barcode_Scanning_(Using_ZBar_SDK)_Sample.htm
The tutorial isn't that good but it helps with setting it up. NOTE: the links they have don't work if you click them..you have to copy and paste the text into your browser.
The database stuff I explained below still is relevant but ignore the parts about zxing.

**Best of luck to you!**

**Original answer**
I may be able to help somewhat for you SQL issues. Do you have any database helper set up?
First off I would google around and find a simply database example to set up the database. There are a number of good ones out there that show you how to set up a database in SQLite for android. The one I used to learn some of the basics:`http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/` . You can use the example of Book to create a product class with all the values for columns that match your needs. Then you simply create automatic getters and setters with eclipse click "Source -> generate getters and setters". Onces you've done that you can use the tutorial below to set up your qr scanner. As for keeping the window open, I don't think you need to do that. Just create an activity that the scanner closes into. In that acticity you can have the output and have the scan results compared to the database.

I was able to use the tutorial `http://%20http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162` to integrate zxing into my app. Once I did that

An example of parsing the data from the qr code:

First you call the scan:

```
public void onClick(View v){
            //respond to clicks
            if(v.getId()==R.id.scanQRButton){
                //scan
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The scan results code then looks like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //retrieve scan result
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);



    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();



    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Now the finishing method for the scan button:

```
public void onClick(View v){
            //respond to clicks
            if(v.getId()==R.id.scanQRButton){
                //scan
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


                formatTxt.setText( "Scan Initiated");
                contentTxt.setText(" Scan Results: " + scanContent);

                if(scanContent != null){

                    String userid,medname,tabstaken,dob;

                                    // Here I am breaking apart the scan results and 
                                   //saving them into variables. 
                             //Do this then call the database for your product and compare
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanContent, ",");
                         // token 0
                         dob = st.nextToken();
                         //token 1
                         medname = st.nextToken();
                         //token 2
                         tabstaken = st.nextToken();
                         //token 3
                         //rxnumber
                    // So here you setup the db so you can access it
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                //This is used to call the results
                    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                           //Use a method such as getProductResults() for your case
                    user = db.getUserDetails();
enter code here

                    //An example of me storing the user
                    userid = user.get("uid");
                    //debug.setText("Userid: "+ userid+ " medname: " + medname + " tabs: " +tabstaken);

                    UserLogEntry userlog = new UserLogEntry(getApplicationContext(),userid,medname,tabstaken);
                    userlog.addUserLog();

                }   
            }
        }
```

If you need to see my database class let me know. Obviously this isn't the exact code you need, but it shows you how to use the results from the QR and call the DB results to do comparisons. Hopefully its helpful